# Docker dotnet build fails with error NU1301

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I wrote a simple project in .Net 8 and a `Dockerfile` to create a docker image for it on my Ubuntu Server.

I ran it once and it worked great, but now for some reason the build fails with the following error: "error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json."](https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.%22)

It does work with an empty project containing only the `csproj` and `Program.cs`, but when I try to build one of my libraries project that also doesn't have any dependencies it shows this error again.

The error is not shown when I run `dotnet publish` on the server directly.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# One of the library projects
COPY Domain Domain
RUN dotnet publish "Domain/Domain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 1883
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Firebase.dll"]
```

This is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The only things I remember I changed from last time it worked are:

1. .Net version from 7 to 8, but returning it to7 didn't help
2. Uninstalling dotnet, but reinstalling it didn't solve the issue either.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some Nuget chache issue try this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# One of the library projects
COPY Domain Domain
RUN dotnet nuget locals all --clear && \
    dotnet publish "Domain/Domain.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0 AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 1883
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Firebase.dll"]
```

Comment: Nope. Still shows the same issue...